# AWS Glue - cron for n-th working day of month

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I need to schedule a Glue job to run on first working day of month. How to config a proper way to achieve it?

Using `day` and `week_day` together throws CDK syntax error.

```
    self.glue_trigger = glue.CfnTrigger(
        self,
        "GlueTrigger",
        actions=[
            glue.CfnTrigger.ActionProperty(job_name=stack_configuration.job_name)
        ],
        type="SCHEDULED",
        name=f"{stack_configuration.job_name}-trigger",
        schedule=events.Schedule.cron(
            minute="00", hour="06", day="01", week_day="MON-FRI"
        ).expression_string,
        start_on_creation=False,
    )
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible with cron.